# Strongswan site-to-site VPN initiated but no traffic

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I´ve seen this sort of question posted a few times before, but so far, none of them have solved my issue.

I'm trying to set up an IKEv2 VPN on an VM in GCP using Strongswan. The connection seems to be set up correctly, but no packets are routed and I can't ping the IP address of the VPN client.

My server's internal network is 10.164.0.0/20

***ipsec statusall***

```
root@vpn-gateway-vodafone:/home/alxtbk# ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.5.1, Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64, x86_64):
  uptime: 4 minutes, since Mar 22 14:22:20 2019
  malloc: sbrk 1478656, mmap 0, used 418352, free 1060304
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 4
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown
Listening IP addresses:
  10.164.0.17
Connections:
      myconn:  %any...85.205.30.142  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s
      myconn:   local:  [35.204.88.19] uses pre-shared key authentication
      myconn:   remote: [85.205.30.142] uses pre-shared key authentication
      myconn:   child:  10.164.0.0/20 === 10.2.0.0/20 TUNNEL, dpdaction=hold
Routed Connections:
      myconn{1}:  ROUTED, TUNNEL, reqid 1
      myconn{1}:   10.164.0.0/20 === 10.2.0.0/20
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
      myconn[1]: ESTABLISHED 4 minutes ago, 10.164.0.17[35.204.88.19]...85.205.30.142[85.205.30.142]
      myconn[1]: IKEv2 SPIs: 9bbb1dde62c00c0c_i* 8fb78440b271f60b_r, pre-shared key reauthentication in 2 hours
      myconn[1]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048
      myconn{2}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: c2c9e607_i 5650382b_o
      myconn{2}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 252 bytes_o (3 pkts, 239s ago), rekeying in 44 minutes
      myconn{2}:   10.164.0.0/20 === 10.2.0.0/20
```

***/var/log/syslog***

```
Mar 22 13:59:52 vpn-gateway-vodafone ipsec[527]: charon stopped after 200 ms
Mar 22 13:59:52 vpn-gateway-vodafone ipsec[527]: ipsec starter stopped
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.5.1, Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64, x86_64)
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem opens
sl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'myconn'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 05[CFG] added configuration 'myconn'
Mar 22 13:59:54 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 07[CFG] received stroke: route 'myconn'
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 11[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'myconn'
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 13[IKE] initiating IKE_SA myconn[1] to 85.205.30.142
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 10.164.0.17[500] to 85.205.30.142[500] (464 bytes)
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 12[NET] received packet: from 85.205.30.142[500] to 10.164.0.17[500] (376 bytes)
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 12[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No ]
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 12[IKE] authentication of '35.204.88.19' (myself) with pre-shared key
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 12[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA myconn
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 12[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) ]
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from 10.164.0.17[500] to 85.205.30.142[500] (252 bytes)
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[NET] received packet: from 85.205.30.142[500] to 10.164.0.17[500] (204 bytes)
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr AUTH SA TSi TSr ]
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[IKE] authentication of '85.205.30.142' with pre-shared key successful
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[IKE] IKE_SA myconn[1] established between 10.164.0.17[35.204.88.19]...85.205.30.142[85.205.30.142]
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[IKE] scheduling reauthentication in 9908s
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10448s
Mar 22 14:00:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 15[IKE] CHILD_SA myconn{2} established with SPIs c9533bb0_i 398968fc_o and TS 10.164.0.0/20 === 10.2.0.0/20
Mar 22 14:00:51 vpn-gateway-vodafone google-accounts: INFO Removing user alxtbk.
Mar 22 14:00:51 vpn-gateway-vodafone google-accounts: INFO Removing user alxtbk from the Google sudoers group.
Mar 22 14:00:51 vpn-gateway-vodafone google_accounts_daemon[690]: Removing user alxtbk from group google-sudoers
Mar 22 14:01:17 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 08[IKE] sending DPD request
Mar 22 14:01:17 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 08[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ ]
Mar 22 14:01:17 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from 10.164.0.17[500] to 85.205.30.142[500] (76 bytes)
Mar 22 14:01:17 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 07[NET] received packet: from 85.205.30.142[500] to 10.164.0.17[500] (76 bytes)
Mar 22 14:01:17 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 07[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL response 2 [ ]
Mar 22 14:01:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 10[IKE] sending DPD request
Mar 22 14:01:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 10[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL request 3 [ ]
Mar 22 14:01:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from 10.164.0.17[500] to 85.205.30.142[500] (76 bytes)
Mar 22 14:01:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 13[NET] received packet: from 85.205.30.142[500] to 10.164.0.17[500] (76 bytes)
Mar 22 14:01:47 vpn-gateway-vodafone charon: 13[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL response 3 [ ]
```

**iptables**

```
root@vpn-gateway-vodafone:/home/alxtbk# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**ip xfrm policy**

```
root@vpn-gateway-vodafone:/home/alxtbk# ip xfrm policy
src 10.2.0.0/20 dst 10.164.0.0/20 
        dir fwd priority 189760 ptype main 
        tmpl src 85.205.30.142 dst 10.164.0.17
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.2.0.0/20 dst 10.164.0.0/20 
        dir in priority 189760 ptype main 
        tmpl src 85.205.30.142 dst 10.164.0.17
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.164.0.0/20 dst 10.2.0.0/20 
        dir out priority 189760 ptype main 
        tmpl src 10.164.0.17 dst 85.205.30.142
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket in priority 0 ptype main 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
        socket out priority 0 ptype main
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Between what IPs/hosts are you trying to transmit packets? Also, did you read [Forwarding and Split-Tunneling](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling) on the strongSwan wiki.

Comment: Remote Site: 85.205.30.142, Subnet 10.2.0.0/20, My Site: 35.204.88.19, Subnet: 10.164.0.0/24.

Comment: You didn't clarify the actual IPs of the hosts, but 10.164.0.0/24 is part of 10.164.0.0/20 so traffic between the mentioned subnets should be covered. You'd have to debug the traffic flow (e.g. via traffic counters, traffic captures or firewall debugging) to see where packets might get dropped or routed incorrectly.

Comment: See my last comment, it contains all the ips. Or what am I missing?